# Rename the product name(the project identifier is given while integratting facebook) in ios?

Tags: ios

I am developing an app in ios and I am using xcode 7. I want to change my product name since the name of app containing more place in iphone .**But I gave my project's identifier name in facebook integration**. If I change the product name will it affect the facebook login in my app? Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will, you will have to update the provided project identifier in facebook for developers web page. 
Go to :
[developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)
Go to your apps --> settings --> basics
 Select your app and change your project Identifier.
Change the bundle identifier in your app's settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can we update that @l.vasilev